# Separate comma values into individual values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to separate columns in SQL Server

Table: columnsseparates

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[columnsseparates](
    [id] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [name] [varchar](500) NULL
) 
INSERT [dbo].[columnsseparates] ([id], [name]) VALUES (N'1,2,3,4', N'abc,xyz,mn')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[columnsseparates] ([id], [name]) VALUES (N'4,5,6', N'xy,yz')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[columnsseparates] ([id], [name]) VALUES (N'7,100', N'yy')
INSERT [dbo].[columnsseparates] ([id], [name]) VALUES (N'101', N'oo,yy')

GO
```

based on above data I want output like below:

```
id   |  Name 
1    |abc
2    |xyz
3    |mn
4    |null
4    |xy
5    |yz
6    |null
7    |yy
100  |null
101  |oo
null |yy
```

How to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Comment: A year's worth of questions and not a single one marked as answered. You should consider doing your part for this forum.

Answer (score 2):

Storing non-atomic values in column is a sign that schema should be normalised.

---

Naive approach using `PARSENAME`(up to 4 comma separated values):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.id, s.name
FROM [dbo].[columnsseparates]
CROSS APPLY(SELECT REVERSE(REPLACE(id,',','.')) id,REVERSE(REPLACE(name, ',','.')) name) sub
CROSS APPLY(VALUES (REVERSE(PARSENAME(sub.id,1)), REVERSE(PARSENAME(sub.name,1))),
                   (REVERSE(PARSENAME(sub.id,2)), REVERSE(PARSENAME(sub.name,2))),
                   (REVERSE(PARSENAME(sub.id,3)), REVERSE(PARSENAME(sub.name,3))),
                   (REVERSE(PARSENAME(sub.id,4)), REVERSE(PARSENAME(sub.name,4))) 
         ) AS s(id, name)
ORDER BY s.id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=74dee4a3da0929a965f80f5dba10d340)**

Output:

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|      |      |
|      | yy   |
|   1  | abc  |
| 100  |      |
| 101  | oo   |
|   2  | xyz  |
|   3  | mn   |
|   4  |      |
|   4  | xy   |
|   5  | yz   |
|   6  |      |
|   7  | yy   |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* you have more than 4 values, then you'll to use a string splitter that can return the ordinal value. I use [`delimitedsplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) here:

```
WITH Ids AS(
       SELECT cs.id,
              cs.name,
              DS.ItemNumber,
              DS.Item
       FROM dbo.columnsseparates cs
            CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD (cs.id,',') DS),
Names AS (
       SELECT cs.id,
              cs.name,
              DS.ItemNumber,
              DS.Item
       FROM dbo.columnsseparates cs
            CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD (cs.[name],',') DS)
SELECT I.Item AS ID,
       N.Item AS [Name]
FROM Ids I
     FULL OUTER JOIN Names N ON I.id = N.id
                            AND I.ItemNumber = N.ItemNumber
ORDER BY CASE WHEN I.Item IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         TRY_CONVERT(int,I.Item);
```